# how to pip install with proxy

Tags: python, proxy

I tried this command

```
pip install --proxy="username:password@192.168.1.1:3128" packagename
```

and the error message say:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip-1.5.5-py3.5.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
File "/usr/local/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip-1.5.5-py3.5.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
File "/usr/local/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip-1.5.5-py3.5.egg/pip/req.py", line 1177, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
File "/usr/local/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip-1.5.5-py3.5.egg/pip/index.py", line 194, in find_requirement
    page = self._get_page(main_index_url, req)
File "/usr/local/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip-1.5.5-py3.5.egg/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_page
    session=self.session,
File "/usr/local/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip-1.5.5-py3.5.egg/pip/index.py", line 670, in get_page
    resp = session.get(url, headers={"Accept": "text/html"})
File "/usr/local/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip-1.5.5-py3.5.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 395, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip-1.5.5-py3.5.egg/pip/download.py", line 237, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip-1.5.5-py3.5.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 383, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip-1.5.5-py3.5.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 486, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip-1.5.5-py3.5.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 305, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
File "/usr/local/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip-1.5.5-py3.5.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 206, in get_connection
    except_on_missing_scheme(proxy)
File "/usr/local/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip-1.5.5-py3.5.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/utils.py", line 631, in except_on_missing_scheme
    raise MissingSchema('Proxy URLs must have explicit schemes.')
pip._vendor.requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Proxy URLs must have explicit schemes.
```

By the way, I remember if the username or password has the interpunction like "." it must be replaced with something but I forget about that. Can anyone remind me of that? Thanks!

Comment: Always remember to format your question correctly. :)

Comment: A workaround may be setting environment variable `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I have already set the http_proxy and https_proxy in /etc/profile and exprot them but nothing changed.

Comment: Finally I got the solution~ My pip version is too low ,it`s just 1.5. I update the latest version 9.x then set the http_proxy and https_proxy, then input the command: pip install packagename --trusted-host pypi.python.org

Comment: @KevinNi glad this helps :)  From the exception info we read `Proxy URLs must have explicit schemes`, so maybe you should run `pip install --proxy="http://username:password@192.168.1.1:3128" packagename`. Notice the `http://` added.

Comment: 咱还是讲中文吧哈哈哈哈，wo zai shang hai~

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this issue too. After many expeiments with pip and easy_install proxy settings I give up and donwloaded whl files from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).
and install them:

```
pip install SomePackage-1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```